# Rails nested attributes validation force save parent firstly

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-5

I have 2 models like:

```
class Father < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :children
    accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
end



class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :father
    validate :validate_money

    def validate_money
      children = Child.where(id: self.father.id)
      sum_of_children_pocket_money = my_func # function for getting sum of all pocket money of all children
      if sum_of_children_pocket_money > self.father.money
        errors.add(:pocket_money, "My error message!!!")
      end
    end
  end
```

and initially I have:

and when pass passengers_attributes to update customer (id=1) like

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Father 1",
  money: 1000,
  children: [
    {
      name: "Child 1",
      id: 1,
      pocket_money: 500
    }
  ]
}
```

and then I am sending for update:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "Father 1",
  money: 2000,
  children: [
    {
      name: "Child 1",
      id: 1,
      pocket_money: 1500
    }
  ]
}
```

So I am getting an error in my validation because it starts `sum_of_children_pocket_money > self.father.money` comparison and `sum_of_children_pocket_money` is equal to 1500 but `self.father.money` still 1000. How can I fix this?

Comment: Your problem is that children get saved before the parent. In your controller method for updating the records, you'll need to create 2 separate methods to update the parent and child record individually. If you update the parent first, validate that, and then try the child, you should get the outcome you're looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Moving the validation logic from Child to Father should solve the problem.

```
class Father < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :children
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :children
  validate :validate_money

  def validate_money
    children = Child.where(id: id)
    sum_of_children_pocket_money = my_func # function for getting sum of all pocket money of all children
    if sum_of_children_pocket_money > money
      errors.add(:pocket_money, "My error message!!!")
    end
  end
end



class Child < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :father
end
```